# Onsenui: sliding menu + camera

Tags: javascript, onsen-ui, monaca

I'm using monaca ide to develop a simple app, and using the slinding menu of onsenui I found that usually when I take a photo reload the page, so the photo doesn't appear on the page. Seems to be random, sometimes happen sometimes doesn't, and I could find why. Any idea?

**UPDATE:**

Here you could see the controller where action is handle:

var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', []);

```
appControllers
    .controller('parkingCtrl',  [
        '$scope',
        'appGlobals',
        function($scope, appGlobals) {
            $scope.snapPhoto = function() {
                navigator.camera.getPicture (onSuccess, onFail, {
                    quality: 50,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                    targetWidth: 100
                });


            //A callback function when snapping picture is success.
            function onSuccess (imageURI) {
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                     $scope.imageURI = imageURI;
                });
            }

            //A callback function when snapping picture is fail.
            function onFail (message) {
                alert ('Error occured: ' + message);
            }
        }
    ])
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this happens on Android.

When you call the function to take picture, the Camera app take over, and now your app is in the background. If you take big picture and your device has small memory, your device will be in low memory state, and it has to kill some background apps to free the memory. In some case, your app is killed and when you return back from the Camera app, your app is restarted.

A work around is to limit the quality or the size of the picture.

This is the reference to the api:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, 
                            onFail, 
                            { quality: 75, 
                              allowEdit: true,
                              destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL,
                              targetWidth: 100,
                             }
 );
```

Here is the complete options:

```
{ quality : 75,
  destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
  allowEdit : true,
  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  targetWidth: 100,
  targetHeight: 100,
  popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: false };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tamura. Yes, I was doing similar to the code you show me and I testing on an android device(moto g). This is my code:

`navigator.camera.getPicture (onSuccess, onFail, {
   quality: 50,
   destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
   saveToPhotoAlbum: true
});`

I tried to reduce the quality and the targetWidth/Height, but without successful. Could be something wrong my code?

Comment: I have added the code from the controller to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

but your case is different..

1) your pic could be so big. so insted of just `reload`ing the page you should `hard reload` that page
   right click on back button

Comment: it's a mobile app, theres is no right click. Anyway, the problem is that the page should't reload.

Comment: okey,  can you please  make  FIDDLE REPRESENTATION AND LINK IN YOUR QUESTION

Comment: I think you don't understand what I'm talking about. As I wrote before, I'm asking about a problem of mobile framework for a native app(not a web a app for the browser) on the monaca IDE. This can't be represented on jsfiddle. Thanks anyway.